# I am looking for a list of Tool pieces with piano/keyboards

Tags: rock, metal, tool

I may join a friend's music band so she told me to practice something from [Tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tool_%28band%29). Now I am looking for a list of songs from Tool with a piano or keyboard part.

Comment: As a keyboardist myself, you can make up parts on songs that don't have any and it is a fairly common thing to do. Off the top of my head, I can't name one tool song that has any keyboard parts in it so I'd start thinking down that path if I were you.

Comment: i added my own answer but yours is a good suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up scrambling trough every album page on wikipedia. I didn't check singles.

*These are the tracks that has someone listed as keyboardist\whatever.*

Here are the results:

- *Tool*

  - **Aenima**

    - ```
      Intermission
      ```
    - ```
      Third Eye
      ```
  - **Salival**

    - ```
      Message to Harry Manback II
      ```
    - ```
      Third Eye
      ```

This is Wikipedia so it may, or may not be a trusted source.

**Feel free to update this answer in case new albums are published.**